# ¿Como generar un numero correlativo en asp.net mvc C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Deseo generar un numero que incremente en 1 ya que estoy creando un archivo pdf usando `IText` y deseo mostrar el numero Ticket único cada vez que se descarga el pdf.

He tratado de crear un contador pero el valor no cambia. Cada vez que se descarga el archivo se mantiene en el valor inicial.

El archivo pdf posteriormente será guardado en base de datos. Una forma sería traer el id identity en el momento que se guarda el pdf. Sin embargo, el pdf primero se construye es por ello que no podría obtenerlo antes.

Scripts

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int contador = 1;
            
            string fechaGenerada = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
            string nombreUnico = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhh:mm:ss");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter pw = new PdfWriter(ms);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pw);
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.LETTER);
            document.SetMargins(75, 35, 70, 35);

            String pdfname = "TICKET_INGRESO_"+nombreUnico+".pdf";
            document.SetMargins(75, 35, 70, 35);

            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);

            Table tablaTitulo = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(ConstantesFormato.texto1)).SetFontSize(14).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tablaTitulo.AddCell(cell);

            document.Add(tablaTitulo);

            Table tbReglas = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellReglas = new Cell();

            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto2);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto3);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto4);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto5);
            crearCeldaRegla(tbReglas, cellReglas, ConstantesFormato.texto6);

            document.Add(tbReglas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbHeader = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellHeader = new Cell();
            crearCeldaHeader(tbHeader, cellHeader, ConstantesFormato.titulo1, font);
            crearCeldaHeader(tbHeader, cellHeader, ConstantesFormato.titulo2, font);
            document.Add(tbHeader);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tb3filas = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell3filas = new Cell();

            
            crear2Celdas(tb3filas, cell3filas, ConstantesFormato.nticket, "TCK-" + contador);
            crear2Celdas(tb3filas, cell3filas, ConstantesFormato.fecha, fechaGenerada);


            document.Add(tb3filas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tb9filas = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell9filas = new Cell();


                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.contenedor, "-");

            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "Tmñ/Tipo", "-");


                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.tara, "-");


                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.payload, "-");


            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "ISO", "-");

                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.ffechaFab, "-");

                crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, ConstantesFormato.clase, "-");


            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "Precinto 1", "-");
            crear2Celdas(tb9filas, cell9filas, "Precinto 2", "-");
            document.Add(tb9filas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tb4filas = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cell4filas = new Cell();

                crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, ConstantesFormato.placa, "-");



                crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, ConstantesFormato.transportes, "-");


                crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, ConstantesFormato.conductor, "-");


            crear2Celdas(tb4filas, cell4filas, "Licencia", "-");
            document.Add(tb4filas);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbfilas4 = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellfilas4 = new Cell();
            crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, "Movimiento", "Ingreso");
            crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, "Destino", "Devolución Cliente");

                crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, ConstantesFormato.status, "-");

                crear2Celdas(tbfilas4, cellfilas4, ConstantesFormato.cliente, "-");


            document.Add(tbfilas4);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbObservaciones = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellObservaciones = new Cell();

                crear2Celdas(tbObservaciones, cellObservaciones, ConstantesFormato.observaciones, "-");


            document.Add(tbObservaciones);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));



            Table tbAgentAduana = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellAgentAduana = new Cell();
            crearCeldaFirma(tbAgentAduana, cellAgentAduana, "Ag. Aduana / Emp. Transportes");
            document.Add(tbAgentAduana);

            Table tbfilasInspector = new Table(5).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellfilasInspector = new Cell();

                crear2Celdas(tbfilasInspector, cellfilasInspector, ConstantesFormato.inspector, "-");

            document.Add(tbfilasInspector);
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));
            document.Add(new Paragraph(""));

            Table tbNota = new Table(1).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            Cell cellNota = new Cell();
            crearCelda(tbNota, cellNota, "NOTA. Para acceder a su EIR debe ingresar al portal www.imupesa.com.pe");

            document.Add(tbNota);

            document.Close();
            contador = contador + 1;
            byte[] byteStream = ms.ToArray();
            ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStream.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return File(ms, "application/pdf", pdfname);
            
        }

        int aleatorio(int min, int max)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return rnd.Next(1, 999999999);
        }

        void crearCelda(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);

        }
        void crearCeldaRegla(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);

        }
        void crearCeldaHeader(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1, PdfFont fuente)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetFontSize(14).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetFont(fuente);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
        }

        void crearCeldaFirma(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetFontSize(14).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER).SetBorderTop(new DashedBorder(1f));
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
        }
        void crear2Celdas(Table tabla, Cell celda, String texto1, String valor)
        {
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(texto1)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
            celda = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(":")).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
            celda = new Cell(1, 3).Add(new Paragraph(valor)).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
            tabla.AddCell(celda);
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo pdf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no leí todo tu bloque de código, pero no podrías leer el último ID guardado, antes de generar el PDF? si no devuelve nada, significa que no hay ningún ticket generado antes y tendrías que empezar con el 1

Comment: Deberias limpiar el codigo para mostrar tenes demasiadas lineas comentadas que hace demorar entender y leer tu codigo

Comment: Estimado @L.Ronquillo  es que primero construyo el pdf y es ahi donde necesito ese correlativo Numero Ticket para posteriormente insertarlo a la base de datos.

Comment: por eso, a lo que voy, haz una consulta a la tabla donde guardes los tickets, obtén el último ID. Si encuentra un resultado, lo pasas, si no, por default es 1. Y una vez obteniendo ese valor, ahora si generas el PDF. ¿no es posible?

Comment: Un contador en el controlador se ejecutará en ese request solamente. Si lo que deseas es tener un número incremental, realiza lo que dice el buen @L.Ronquillo de frente en la base de datos y de ahí vas obteniendo el registro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear un método que se encargue de obtener el último ID de la tabla, y utilizar el método para tu proceso original. Podría quedarte algo como esto (en mí ejemplo uso [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/)) y algo de [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries):

```
public int UltimoTicketID()
        {
            Ticket t=context.Tickets.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).LastOrDefault();
            return t!=null?t.Id:1;
            //Obtengo el último registro. Si la consulta devolviera null, asignamos 1 por defecto. si no, devolvemos el ID.
        }
```

Si te das cuenta, mi método es de tipo `int`, así que siempre devuelve un número.

Como nota adicional, estoy utilizando un [If ternario](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) en el return.

Y, finalmente, en tu método original, en la linea donde asignas el contador, utilizarías el método de la siguiente manera:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int contador = UltimoTicketID();
            //continúa tu código normal...
```

Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.

¡Saludos! :D

Comment: Estimado @L. Ronquillo si ello fuese consultado desde un store procedure la consulta sería "Select Max(id) from xxx"  ya que no estoy usando linq.

Comment: 2 cosas @DarwinUM : 1. De acuerdo a la revisón ( https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/418670/revisions ) En ningún lado se menciona si hay SP, o una base de datos en específico. Linq encaja con varias bases de datos. 2. Te están dando tiempo, conocimiento, paciencia, respeto y quizás más cosas, un "gracias" quedaría muy bien. Saludos :D

Comment: Estimado @fredyfx en primer lugar no tenia en mente usar la base de datos  es por ello que no mostré si usaba store procedure y segundo, estoy en una aplicación que no usa linq es por ello la pregunta.Saludos :D.

Comment: @DarwinUM lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Te ayudará a crear mejores preguntas con mayor chance de obtener la respuesta que buscas :D

Comment: si tu intención no es usar una base de datos, tienes que guardar externamente el valor en algún lugar, puedes usar un fichero en vez de una BD, pero la teoría sería la misma, leer el último ticketID, y después asignarlo a la variable que usas para poner en el pdf :D

Comment: @DarwinUM si lo deseas, edito la pregunta para que veas como queda con una consulta directa :D

Comment: si la mejor forma es hacerlo por la bd ese seria la forma